# Why my props returns the index with value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a variable named "subject", it returns the string "Test", and I'm passing it to props child with this:

```
onRowSelect(slotProps) {
      this.subject = { ...slotProps.data.subject.split() };
    }
```

In my component, receiving the value of "subject", it returns this string - `{ "0": "Test" }`.

I wonder why, and how to solve it? Where's the real problem?

Comment: How your `slotProps.data.subject` look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
onRowSelect(slotProps) {
  this.subject = slotProps.data.subject;
}
```

You were using spread on an array into an object, which is why you get {0: "T", 1: "e"} and so on.